# RegEx separating variable after number - jQuery

Tags: jquery, regex

I am handed a variable in the this format:

```
var fubar = e2s2
```

Now, the letters are always the same, but the numbers do change. The numbers can only be 1-9. The ending result I would need something like this:

```
var foo = e2
var bar = s2
```

I'd settle for just the number as well. I just have to have the digit.

Comment: `e2s2` is a sample value or what?

Comment: what are you asking for...a digit or both...

Comment: Either/or ... It really doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regex with replace. following code would work

```
var fubar = "e2s2";
var a = fubar.replace(/\d/g, function(arg){ return arg+ ","}).split(",");
a.pop(); // removing last item.
var foo = a[0];
 var bar = a[1];
```

Comment: Yikes.  Kinda complicated for such a simple problem, don't you think?

Comment: But it will work for any such string eg. e2s2e2er2.

Comment: `var digits = fubar.replace(/\d/g, '').split('');`

Comment: I tried it. the problem is it will remove numeric value from generated string.

Comment: @Madbreaks u have completely misunderstood the question!he doesnt want only digits

Comment: @Anirudha Really?  What does this mean?  "I just have to have the digit."  See my full answer to the question.  The snippet in these comments is just to show Shushil that it need not be so complicated.

Comment: @Madbreaks hmm..op seems 2 be confused

Comment: @Madbreaks ohh...u cant even read i guess

Comment: strictly digit, or both character and digit... it doesn't matter. I just need them separated. This is probably the better route to go in case the client adds future characters to the variable. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 3):

No need for RegEx if it will always be in this form.

```
var foo = fubar.substr(0,2),
    bar = fubar.substr(2);
```

..or, if you just want the digit:

```
var foo = fubar.substr(1,1),
    bar = fubar.substr(3);
```

If you really need a RegEx solution, how about:

```
var digits = fubar.replace(/\d/g, '').split(''),
    foo    = digits[0],
    bar    = digits[1];
```

A million ways to go about it.  But avoid RegEx unless you actually need it.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

This does it with the `split method`

`(?![1-9])`

**OR**

```
(?=[^1-9])
```

**NOTE:**

Use `(?![1-9]|^)` to avoid the blank space that gets included in the resulting array

Answer (score 1):

```
var fubar = 'e2s2' ;

var foo = fubar.substr(0,2) ;
var bar = fubar.substr(2);
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/SgSwG/)

Answer (score 0):

If elements are always in format **one non-digit character followed by one digit character**, then use

```
elements = str.split(/(?=\D)/)
```

to get full elements in an array; and to get just array of numbers (digits), use

```
(numbers = str.split(/\D/)).splice(0, 1);
```

Comment: I like.  Why not just:  `str.split(/\D/)` ?

Comment: an empty space would get generated at the first index..